# Xamarin Webview not giving latitude and longitude

Tags: android, xamarin, webview

I have a web application which showing latitude and longitude data of different location. I am trying to open the same web application using an android app which is developed using web view in Xamarin . But the latitude and longitude is displaying as blank. When i am using a Chrome brwoser it works fine. Please help me.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.layout3);
    web_view = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webview);
    web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    web_view.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
    web_view.SetWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    web_view.SetWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());
    web_view.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
    web_view.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = true;
    web_view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
    web_view.Settings.SetGeolocationEnabled(true);
    web_view.LoadUrl("https://abcd.com");
}


class GeoWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
{
    public override void OnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(string origin, GeolocationPermissions.ICallback callback)
    {
        callback.Invoke(origin, false, false);
    }

}



class HelloWebViewClient:WebViewClient
{
    // For API level 24 and later
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have given location permission manifest ?? and Runtime in 6 and higher version..

Comment: Android Marshmallow introduces an entirely new spin on application permissions in an attempt to not only simplify permissions, but also to reduce the number of permissions needed. You can refer this blog  https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/